# Can't seem to scrape tbody from this website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this website: https://web.archive.org/web/20130725021041/http://www.usatoday.com/sports/nfl/injuries/

```
page = requests.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20130725021041/http://www.usatoday.com/sports/nfl/injuries/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('tbody')
```

soup.find_all('tbody') returns []. I'm not entirely sure why.

This is the tbody part I'm trying to scrape out:

```
<tbody><tr class="page"><td>
                                    7/23/2013


                        </td><td>


                                    Anthony Spencer


                        </td><td>



                                        Cowboys



                        </td><td>


                                    DE


                        </td><td>


                                    Knee


                        </td><td>


                                    Knee


                        </td><td>


                                    Out


                        </td><td>


                                    Is questionable for 9/8 against the NY Giants


                        </td></tr><tr class="page"><td>


                                    7/22/2013


                        </td><td>


                                    Tyrone Crawford


                        </td><td>



                                        Cowboys



                        </td><td>


                                    DE


                        </td><td>


                                    Achilles-tendon


                        </td><td>


                                    Achilles


                        </td><td>


                                    Out


                        </td><td>


                                    Is expected to be placed on injured reserve


                        </td></tr><tr class="page"><td>


                                    7/16/2013


                        </td><td>


                                    Ryan Broyles


                        </td><td>



                                        Lions



                        </td><td>


                                    WR


                        </td><td>


                                    Knee


                        </td><td>


                                    Knee


                        </td><td>


                                    Questionable


                        </td><td>


                                    Is questionable for 9/8 against Minnesota


                        </td></tr><tr class="page"><td>


                                    7/2/2013


                        </td><td>


                                    Jahvid Best


                        </td><td>



                                        Lions



                        </td><td>


                                    RB


                        </td><td>


                                    Concussion


                        </td><td>


                                    Concussion


                        </td><td>


                                    Out


                        </td><td>


                                    Is out indefinitely


                        </td></tr><tr class="page"><td>


                                    7/2/2013


                        </td><td>


                                    Jerel Worthy


                        </td><td>



                                        Packers



                        </td><td>


                                    DE


                        </td><td>


                                    Knee


                        </td><td>


                                    Knee


                        </td><td>


                                    Out


                        </td><td>


                                    Is out indefinitely


                        </td></tr><tr class="page"><td>


                                    7/2/2013


                        </td><td>


                                    JC Tretter


                        </td><td>



                                        Packers



                        </td><td>


                                    TO


                        </td><td>


                                    Ankle


                        </td><td>


                                    Ankle


                        </td><td>


                                    Out


                        </td><td>


                                    Is out indefinitely


                        </td></tr><tr class="page"><td>



                        </td></tr></tbody>
```

Could someone help me out and let me know why the find_all on tbody returns an empty list? Even when i try tr with class page it returns an empty list.

Comment: That's because BS uses a html4 parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with the html. Switch to using 'lxml' as parser instead of 'html.parser'. I'd also just use pandas to be honest.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20130725021041/http://www.usatoday.com/sports/nfl/injuries/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(len(soup.find_all('tbody')))
```

or, more simply for table:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://web.archive.org/web/20130725021041/http://www.usatoday.com/sports/nfl/injuries/')[0]
print(df)
```